# duplicated entry error message to ModelForm in django

Tags: python, django

how to add an error message to be displayed if the user tried to add an entry that is already on the table

**forms.py**

```
class AddCatForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = ['category_name']
        labels = {
        'category_name': ('إسم الفئة الجديدة')
        }
        error_messages  = {
        'category_name': {
        'unique': ('الفئة موجودة بالفعل')
        }
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def add_cat(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddCatForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('/')

    else:

        form = AddCatForm()

        return render(request, "add_cat.html", {'form': form})
```

When i add an entry that is already there , it just does nothing , i want it to view an error

Comment: You have to specify unique attributes that can only appear once. By default the primary key is the only thing that has to be unique. Have a look at models in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be getting an error which you will not see because of your indentation.  Amend it to:

```
def add_cat(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddCatForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('/')

    else:

        form = AddCatForm()

    return render(request, "add_cat.html", {'form': form})
```